# Ruby on Rails form.object does not respond to object methods: undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods

I'm using ryanb's nested_form gem for Rails 3 and am trying to access the object being passed in the form so that I can label the fields that are generated by the form-builder.

I have the following basic structure:

```
Trainer has_many :clients, through: :relationships
Trainer has_many :schedules

Client has_many :trainers, through: :relationships
Client has_many :schedules
```

My view code for the Client#edit page:

```
<% provide(:title, @client.name) %>
<h2><%= link_to @client.name, @client %></h2>

<%= render :partial => 'shared/errors', :locals => { :user => @client } %>

<%= nested_form_for @client do |f| %>

<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add Schedule", :schedules %></p>

<%= f.fields_for :schedules do |schedule_form| %>

        <%= schedule_form.object.trainer.name %>

    <%= schedule_form.date_select :scheduled_date %> 
    <%= schedule_form.link_to_remove "Remove" %>

    <%= schedule_form.hidden_field :trainer_id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :trainer_id %>

    <% end %>

<br><%= f.submit "Create", class: 'btn btn-large btn-primary' %></br>
<% end %>
```

The line `<%= schedule_form.object.trainer.name %>` throws a `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` error.

Here's where it gets weird. I'm going to post a couple scenarios below where I modify that line and then post the output on the page:

```
<%= schedule_form.object.trainer %>
<Trainer:0x007fdcedf3f800>

<%= schedule_form.object.trainer.class %>
Trainer

<%= schedule_form.object.trainer.is_a?(Object) %>
true

<%= schedule_form.object.trainer.respond_to?(:name) %>
true

<%= schedule_form.object.trainer.name %>
undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass

<%= t_id = schedule_form.object.trainer_id %>
1
<%= Trainer.find(t_id) %>

<%= t_id = schedule_form.object.trainer_id %>
1
<%= Trainer.find_by_id(t_id) %>
#<Trainer:0x007fdcedf09660>

<%= t_id = schedule_form.object.trainer_id %>
1
<%= Trainer.find_by_id(t_id).name %>
undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass
```

So basically - I can use the form builder to retrieve the :schedule object and can query it to retrieve the :trainer object (`schedule.trainer` or `schedule.trainer_id`); however, the :trainer object will not respond to any of its instance methods, even though it is, as far as I've been able to tell, an object of the class Trainer.

How can I return `trainer.name`? That's all I want: a label. Please help.

EDIT: Added Trainer Model

```
class Trainer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :clients, through: :relationships
  has_many :schedules

  validates :name, presence: true
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                                                                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, on: :create
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, on: :create

  before_save { |trainer| trainer.email = email.downcase } 

end
```

---

EDIT - added later.

I tried using the following code and it worked as expected:

```
<%= t_id = 1 %>
<%= Trainer.find(t_id).name %>
```

Returns

```
Joe Trainer
```

However:

```
<%= t_id = schedule_form.object.trainer_id %>
  > 1
<%= Trainer.find(t_id) %>
  > Couldn't find Trainer without an ID
<%= Trainer.find_by_id(t_id) %>
  > #<Trainer:0x007fea86b9a168>
<%= Trainer.find_by_id(t_id).name %>
  > undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass
```

So apparently there's some 'extra baggage' with whatever is returned from schedule_form.object. Is there a way to take `t_id = schedule_form.object.trainer_id` and sanitize it so that all I have is a pure integer, unencumbered by any previous history?

Comment: Did you try <%= schedule_form.object.trainer.nil? %>  I admit it's strange behavior.

Comment: The other thing I see that's odd is that your has_many :through relationship isn't set up how I would expect.  I would expect to see it set up as client has_many :trainers, :though => :schedules.  Right now it's :through => :relationships.  Do you have a relationships model somewhere?

Comment: it seems strange. can you provide the code for your trainer class or the complete stack trace ?

Comment: @joeyjoejoejr - there is a Relationship model; it's basically just a join table with a column for :client_id and a column for :trainer_id.
I did try <%= schedule_form.object.trainer.nil? %> and it returned false.

Comment: @RishavRastogi - I added the Trainer model.

Comment: @RishavRastogi I pasted the Full Trace into google docs: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xXvkd5ETjIF4fXYZByzlZkj3jqStPK4hZ3sdtYNIyPk/edit

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, also following the Ryan Bates and Michael Hartls tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing on a Schedule object, but you dit not post that model.

Most likely it crashes because you did not create the schedule using @trainer.schedules.create, but used Schedule.create or Schedule.new... Then the trainer property is not initialized and thus is nil.

Comment: I'm using client.update_attributes to update all the schedules. The trainer property is returning nil even for objects that are already saved to the database. However, schedule_form.object.trainer_id returns the correct id - do you have any idea why I can't search the Trainer based on that? Trainer.find shouldn't be dependent on the schedule being initialized.